# IBM DB2 ON AS400

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange, iseries-navigator, db2-connect

I want to configure IBM DB2 on iseries AS400. The issue is I'm not getting the proper tool for AS400 and I've already installed Data Studio for configure DB2.
I don't have any knowledge regarding AS400 and I'm fresher for IBM technology.
I have already ODBC drivers of iseries. Please help me to find out iseries AS400 setup tool.

Answer (score 3):

DB2 is integrated into OS/400 and all of it's following OS's. To configure DB2 on these platforms, perform a power-on maneuver. If it is already turned on, then DB2 is configured.

BTW, you probably don't have an AS400 but something newer. The hardware is likely Power System or Pure System, and the OS is likely IBM i.

Comment: IBM i documentation https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzahg/ic-homepage.htm

Comment: Basically, I am looking for IBM iseries access setup tool. Can you help me to find that?

Comment: Ok, iSeries Access and DB2 are completely different.What are you trying to do?

Comment: You have to configure db2 on the iseries to work like every other sql database see my answer below.  Its easy you should start talking about it or these new users who are remotely accessing it will fail.

Comment: Ok, so you may have to have the correct ODBC or JDBC configuration, but you don't need any special DB2 configuration. The problems new users will have is thinking that DB2 on IBM i needs the same kind of configuration that Oracle or SQL Server or even DB2 LUW need.  DB2 for i is far more capable in certain respects. You don't need to set the CCSID for the database, just set that in the connection. You don't need to set colating sequence, at the database level. Just set it at the connection level. You don't have any of the other configurations that the other databases need.

Comment: All those configurations that are required by other databases  are either not applicable to DB2 for i, or are configured in the connection properties. You don't configure the database. It is preconfigured by the OS.

Answer (score 0):

Once you get a SQL connection to the AS400 aka system i aka iseries.  Configure the DB by executing this SQL statement in Studio.

```
create collection myas400SQL
```

This will create an as400 library named MYAS400SQL that has the mumbo jumbo journal automatically added meaning this will work like every other SQL database with commit rollback transactions...

Lets try it.

```
CREATE TABLE myas400sql.mytable (myfield char(1))
```

Table mytable can handle commits and rollbacks like any other db you may have used.

Happy Friday.

Comment: Of course you don't even have to do `create collection` if you already have a library. you can just create tables in your existing library. Let's try that: `create table mylib.mytable (myfield char(1))`. You may want to create a journal, but you don't have to. Note: `commits` and `rollbacks` won't work if you don't have a journal. You can treat that like auto-commit.

Comment: Create collection works V7r3.   I never liked the word schema it doesn't sound nice.  AFAIK Create collection is iseries synonym for create schema.  Both create an auto journaling library without a qdftjrn dtaara mumbo jumbo.

Comment: The collection was at one time the way to create a library for DB2/400. There was no `create schema`. But, as IBM brought DB2 in line with standard SQL, they dropped COLLECTION for SCHEMA. It is likely just IBM's aversion to dropping support for things that keeps the DB2 for i proprietary meaning. Collection means different proprietary things to all the major databases. in MySql it is part of the document based extensions. In Oracle, it is an array or a list. In SQL Server, it is a data collection set. Not real sure what that means, but all of them use SCHEMA the same way.